# Is the exceptional set Zariski open?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems

Let $T$ be a smooth projective variety and $f_T : \mathbb {P}^N_T \rightarrow \mathbb {P}^N_T $ be a family of dominant rational maps. The dynamical degree of a dominant rational map $f $ is defined by $\lim_{n \to \infty}(\mathrm {deg}(f^n))^{1/n}$.

Let $E $ be a set of $t \in T $ such that the dynamical degree of $f_t$ is same as $f_T $. Is $E $ is Zariski open? If yes, why?

It looks natural but I have no idea of proof since I have a very few knowledge of algebraic geometry maybe.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not true that your exceptional set is always Zariski open. Here's an example. Consider the map
$$ f_{a,b,c}(X,Y,Z) = [XY, XY+aZ^2, bYZ+cZ^2] : 
\mathbb P^2 \longrightarrow\mathbb P^2
$$
parametrized by $(a,b,c)\in\mathbb A^3$. Then generically $\delta(f_{a,b,c})=2$, but it's a fun calculation to show that $\delta(f_{a,b,c})\lt2$ (strict inequality) if and only if $c^2=-(\zeta+\zeta^{-1})ab$ for some root of unity $\zeta$. So your $E$ is the complement of a union of a countable union of Zariski closed subsets of $\mathbb A^3$, parameterized by roots of unity.

At the risk of self-promotion, Greg Call and I wrote a paper discussing specialization issues of the dynamical degree. 
Degeneration of Dynamical Degrees in Families of Maps
(https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.02119).

Generalizing a conjecture in that paper (for $\dim(T)=1$), one might guess:

**Conjecture** For all $\epsilon > 0$, the set
$$ \{ t\in T : \delta(f_t)\le\delta(f_T)-\epsilon \}$$
is a Zariski closed set.

Comment: Thank you. I was confused with 'degree', 12p in your paper. Here is another question about your paper. In 5p, proposition 11. (c), [0,0,1] is also an exceptional case, right? And the last case, setting $x=c$, not 1,$ y=1, z=0,$ then we can find a non empty preimage so I think that $cx-cy+az=0$ is right condition.

Comment: @LWW I'll have to think about your comments. It might be better to continue this conversation offline. Why don't you send me an email (my address is in the paper) and we can discuss it.

Comment: Okay, I'll send you.